# Branchless way to set all bits if no bits are set?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, branchless

I'm looking for a branchless implementation of the following:

```c
int f(int c) {
  if (c == 0) {
    return 0xffffffff; // all bits set
  } else {
    return c;
  }
}
```

I haven't come across any clever ways to do this. Any tricks?

Comment: Compiling this as-is leads to a branchless implementation using the `cmovne` instruction, at least on GCC 12.2 with compiler options `-O2`.

Comment: There are ways to do this purely with bitwise operations (without relying on any particular optimization that a compiler may or may not do), is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Nick ODell, there is a good chance that a compiler will already compile this code to instructions without a branch. A formulation making this even more likely is `x - (x == 0)` or `x - !!x`, which a compiler would typically be able to implement without branches by using CPU specific features. You can even try to replace this by a formulation purely based on bit manipulation. E.g. `((x - 1) & ~x) >> 31` (`x` unsigned) is `1` only if `x == 0`, and `0` otherwise. So

```
x - (((x - 1) & ~x) >> 31)
```

would be a completely branchless implementation of `f`. In practice I would expect it to be slower though than whatever the compiler generates for the other formulations.

Comment: From playing with a dozen compilers on Compiler Explorer `x - (x == 0)` seems to work the best across all processor architectures, but occasionally (e.g. MSVC 19.28) generates code that is less efficient than the code generated for the function in the question. Conversely, for some platforms (e.g. gcc for RISC-V, MIPS) the function from the question compiles to branch-y code.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast `c` to the `bool` type to get 1 if any of the bits are set and 0 otherwise. Use `_Bool` or `#include <stdbool.h>` unless you are using C23.

Then subtract 1. If the result of the previous step was one, this will result in -1 which is all 1 bits on a two's complement system. To make this even more portable you could cast them to `unsigned` types first. Otherwise the result will be 0.

The previous step will result in a number that is -1 if `c` is 0 and otherwise 0. Bitwise OR the number with `c` will simply result in -1 if the number is -1 or leave `c` unchanged otherwise.

```
c | ((bool)c - 1)
```